# Services set with status code different from 200 are failed

Tags: java, groovy, soapui, http-status-codes

My goal is to test my services depending on their service `HTTP status`.
When I launch my request, just services set by the 200 value succeed but another status like `400`, `500`, etc. failed that can be seen on the logs.

I am using `soaPUI` for a testing application located on the Tomcat server. The tracks of my requests are logged on another application before that test, the `HTTP status` was unique and set for all called services.

Now, for my test I have to dissociate the `HTTP status code` of my services, that is to each service with its own `HTTP status` depending on my tests needs.

**code:**

```java
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.mock.RestMockResult
import java.nio.charset.Charset
import com.eviware.soapui.model.mock.MockRunListener
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

httpStatus = 200

def writeOut(fileEndPath, mockResult, method) { 
def jsonFile = new File(dataDir + fileEndPath)    
log.info "jsonFile " + jsonFile               
    if("GET".equalsIgnoreCase(method)){
        mockRequest.httpResponse.status = httpStatus
        mockRequest.httpResponse.setContentType("application/json")
        mockRequest.httpResponse.writer.print(jsonFile.getText("UTF-8"))
        mockRequest.httpResponse.writer.flush()
    }       
}

def isFileToReturnExist(fileToReturn){
    def fileExist = false

    if(fileToReturn != null){
        def fileToTest =  new File(dataDir + fileToReturn)
        if( fileToTest.exists() && fileToTest.canRead()){
            fileExist = true
        }
    }
    return fileExist
}

   dataDir = new File(context.getMockService().getProject().path).parent

   def services = ["Service1", "Service2", "Service3", "Service4", 
   "Service5", "Service6", "Service7","Service8"]
   def status = [200, 400, 200, 200, 400, 200, 200, 200]
   def temp = 
   mockRequest.getHttpRequest().getQueryString().split("fields=")

   if ( temp.size() == 2){
    temp =  temp[1].split("&")
    if ( temp.size() > 0){  
        infos = temp[0]
        for(int i=0; i< services.size; i++){
                el = services[i]
            if ( infos.split(",").size() > 1 && (infos.split(",") 
        [1]== el || infos.split(",")[0]== el)){
                infos = el
                httpStatus = status[i]
                break;
            }
         }
      }     
    }
    inf = infos.split(",")

    log.info inf.size()

    def docroot = "/pns/"+infos 

    def method = mockRequest.getHttpRequest().getMethod(); 
    def queryString = mockRequest.getHttpRequest().getPathInfo()
    log.info "method " + method 
    log.info "queryString " + queryString
    if(queryString != null){    
    def list = queryString.trim().split("/")
    def credValue = list[list.size()-1].tokenize('|')[0]

    def typecredential = ""
    def lstcredtemp = list[list.size()-2].tokenize('|')
    if ( lstcredtemp.size() > 0){   
        typecredential = lstcredtemp[0] + "_"
    }       

    if("GET".equalsIgnoreCase(method)){
        fileToReturn = docroot + "/Response_" + typecredential + 
     credValue + ".json"
    }
}

   if(!isFileToReturnExist(fileToReturn)){
     log.info "le fichier " + fileToReturn + " n'existe pas"
     fileToReturn = docroot+"/error.json" 
   }

   RestMockResult mockResult = new RestMockResult( mockRequest )

   if (fileToReturn != null) {
     writeOut(fileToReturn, mockResult, method)
   }

log.info typecredential + " fileToReturn : " + fileToReturn
return mockResult
```

The log application is supposed to trace for services with status `200` a START line and STOP line with OK.

For services with status code `400` (according to the code) are traced with a START line and a STOP line with KORG, the return code and the description of the error.

But my actual results are that for services with the status code `400`, I get just the START line, but not the STOP line with error description and so on.

```
NTL;NTL;FRO;GetMyServices;START;;;IBTIs;IBTIt;.......;
NTL;FRO;SP;getPns[Service1];START;;;IBTIs;IBTIt;
NTL;FRO;SP;getPns[Service1];STOP;OK;;IBTIs;IBTIt;
NTL;FRO;SP;getPns[Service3];START;;;IBTIs;IBTIt;
NTL;FRO;SP;getPns[Service5];START;;;IBTIs;IBTIt;
NTL;FRO;SP;getPns[Service2];START;;;IBTIs;IBTIt;
NTL;FRO;SP;getPns[Service4];START;;;IBTIs;IBTIt;
NTL;FRO;ADVISE;getProposal;START;;;IBTIs;IBTIt;
NTL;FRO;SPX;getProposal;STOP;OK;200;IBTIs;IBTIt;
NTL;FRO;SP;getPns[Service3];STOP;OK;;IBTIs;IBTIt;
NTL;FRO;SP;getPns[Service6];START;;;IBTIs;IBTIt;
NTL;FRO;SP;getPns[Service4];STOP;KORG;Mapping 
exception;IBTIs;IBTIt;Mapping exception reponse pnsGatape;
NTL;FRO;SP;getPns[Service6];STOP;OK;;IBTIs;IBTIt;
NTL;NTL;FRO;GetMyServices;STOP;OK;;IBTIs;IBTIt;....
```